# How do I create JPA EntityManagerFactory that works in container and standalone applications?

Tags: java, unit-testing, gwt, jpa, resin

I'm new to JPA so after searching for a while and trying I could not figure how to do the following thing.

I want to use JPA annotated classes in unit tests, production - resin app server, and in development mode for GWT (jetty).

The problem is that I could use Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory together with META-INF/persistence.xml in unit tests and it works fine. However, it does not work on resin and I get the same error in GWT development mode.

I could get it working on resin by using @Inject annotation and resin-web.xml but not sure how to use it in GWT dev mode.

I'd like to use the same code if possible for all 3 cases: unit tests, Jetty for GWT, and resin in production. I also like to let resin handle connection pooling, and avoid using Spring if possible.

Are the any tutorials that cover this particular case or any code samples? What are the best practices?

Comment: Does GWT dev mode have guice available?

Comment: I think I can use guice and code injection myself. This is actually what I was thinking of doing. Could you provide a code snippet on how to inject using guice in these cases please?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're open to using Guice, Guice can piggyback off the existing @Inject annotation.

So, the idea here is to do the same thing that Resin does when it runs your code. Resin recognizes the @Inject annotation, finds the appropriate class and instantiates, than injects that value. We can get Guice to do the same thing for us for your unit test and GWT modes.

The biggest change is you'll have to make a seperate profile for your persistence.xml. Copy your existing file and change the name. For instance, if your existing PU is "myJPAUnit", in the new file, name it "myJPAUnitLocal" like this:

```
 <persistence-unit name="myJPAUnitLocal" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
 </persistence-unit>
```

The other key change is to change `transaction-type` to `RESOURCE_LOCAL` as in the above example because your transactions aren't managed by a container.

I won't cover the pre-reqs, because there are a lot of good tutorials on Google about running Junit tests and webapps with Guice, but I thought that might be a tripping point for you. The remaining steps are something like: add the Guice filter, extend the GuiceServletContextListener, add the JPA injector to that, add your listener to the web.xml.

- How to initialize Guice in a webapp: http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ServletModule
- How to add a JPA injector to Guice: http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/JPA

Good luck!

Comment: Hi exabrial. Thanks for your response. I used guice injection as described here: http://www.benmccann.com/dev-blog/hibernate-with-jpa-annotations-and-guice/. It works fine in unit tests. I'm not sure how to conditionally inject EntityManager with guice when I run on Jetty and to let Resin inject in production. If I understand correctly you suggest to use presence of guice listener in web.xml to do that conditionally.